# Implement Dispose or Finalize?

Tags: vb.net, dispose, finalizer

```
Class ComponentsContainer   ' a component contains other components'
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.Component

    Private foo as New Component
    Private bar as New Component

Protected Override Sub Finalize()
    foo.Dispose()  ' HERE ? '
    bar.Dispose()
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If disposing Then
        foo.Dispose() ' OR HERE ? '
        bar.Dispose()
    End If
    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
End Sub 
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not (don't have to) Dispose managed resources from the Finalizer:

```
Protected Override Sub Finalize()
    ' foo.Dispose()  ' 
    ' bar.Dispose()  '
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub
```

And from that it follows that if your class does not have *unmanaged* resources you don't need a Finalizer at all.

<strike>Note: Your class is missing the `Public Sub Dispose()` overload.</strike>

Edit:

Since `foo` and `bar` are managed resources (extending Component) you only need the `Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)` method. The version in the question is correct. And simply drop the `Finalize()`.

Comment: Suspect the `Public Sub Dispose` overload comes from the base class

Comment: I updated the code that explains from where I inherit. I have a component that contains 2 other components.

Comment: As I understand from the BlueMonkMN post, you'd suggest to remove both overrided methods: Dipose and Finalize

Comment: @serhio, to be clear: use 1 version of Dispose. Which one is open to debate, not that important.

Answer (score 3):

The finalizer should call this class' Dispose passing false for the disposing parameter rather than directly disposing of objects this class owns.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28VS.80%29.aspx).

**Edit:** So to answer the question, disposing of owned objects should be done in Dispose, not Finalize.

**Edit 2:** Notice, this means that if the object is finalized without being disposed, then Dispose will only get called (by Finalize) with the "false" parameter, and the child objects will not be disposed by this class.  This is correct because they are managed objects and will be finalized when the framework feels like it if not explicitly disposed.

Comment: Correct. And in this example, Dispose(False) does nothing (except maybe in the baseclass). Removing both Finalize and Dispose(bool) would be the best option.

Comment: so, finally, where should I dispose foo and bar?

Comment: Is it correct Henk when says that I should do nothing at all (remove both Finalize and Dispose overrides)?

Comment: I used to think that if your class has only managed resources you don't need to implement dispose.  But I have found, this can significantly impact performance (waiting for a bitmap dispose of itself takes much longer and much more memory), and I now always implement dispose to dispose properly of managed resources more deterministically.  I would be interested to hear more about this.

Answer (score 2):

What are you inheriting from? I suspect it may be [System.ComponentModel.Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.container.aspx), directly or indirectly.

In which case, you don't need to do anything. System.ComponentModel.Container [automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa319623(VS.71).aspx) disposes of any components it contains, in its `Dispose` method. Let it alone - that has to be the easiest way to implement the dispose/finalise pattern.

Comment: Inheriting from `System.ComponentModel.Component` . Updated the code.

Comment: Why not inherit from Container instead? That's what it's for.

Comment: In the real project I use VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Shape(that is a component). So, I have a custom (multiline)shape that contains some internal shapes(lines).

Answer (score 1):

`Dispose` is when you explicitly want to release some resources before the garbage collector frees the object.

`Finalize` is automatically called when or if the garbage collector gets around to freeing the object.

If you have many objects that hold on to resource's then since you should not be controlling garbage collection you should be using Dispose.

From the framework documentation:

> Note that even when you provide
>   explicit control by way of Dispose,
>   you should provide implicit cleanup
>   using the Finalize method. Finalize
>   provides a backup to prevent resources
>   from permanently leaking if the
>   programmer fails to call Dispose.

[Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: So, explicit cleanup in my case should be `foo.Dispose` and `bar.Dispose` , now what could mean "implicit cleanup" in Finalize in my case I don't see...